# catalog_product_collection_load_before and getLoadedProductCollection

Tags: event-observer, collection, join

I have a strange problem, which gives me the feeling i missed some concept:

In an observer triggered via event dispatch `<catalog_product_collection_load_before>`
i fetch the collection and do a join:

```
        $select->joinLeft(
            array('partner_stock' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('xxx_partner_stock')),
            "`e`.`sku`=`partner_stock`.`sku` AND `partner_stock`.`customer_id`={$partnerId}",
            array('stock_id'=>'stock_id')
        );
```

In a later observer listening to `<catalog_product_collection_load_after>` i fetch the select and its missing the join. Any clou why?

Comment: Have you actually inspected the select object to confirm the join is missing?

Comment: of course i did a $collection->getSelect()->__toString() in the load before and load after observer. Its there before, but its gone in the after observer.

Comment: It could be that some other code is calling `reset()` against the select object, have you looked for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the `catalog_block_product_list_collection` observer used in Mage_Review (`review/observer::catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml`). Within this observer method, Magento loads the collection (`$productCollection->load()`). Better to use this event to do what you want: `catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after`.

Order of events:

1. catalog_block_product_list_collection (used by review module, after collection is loaded its not editable anymore)
2. catalog_product_collection_load_before
3. catalog_product_collection_load_after

Comment: perfect. it was the review observer!