# Load out-of-stock products after the in-stock products in the category listing

Tags: product, category

I want to show first all in-stock products and then out-of-stock products respectively and sort by price in the ascending order.

Following is my code. In my local.xml I wrote the following code for the price from low to high

```
<catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>asc</dir></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

and I wrote an observer to show all out-of-stock products last, i.e., after loading all in-stock products. For this I had used the catalog_product_collection_load_before event

```
$collection = $observer->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('_inventory_table'=>$collection->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
            "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id",
            array('is_in_stock', 'manage_stock')
        );
        $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
            'on_top',
            '(CASE WHEN (((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 1) AND (_inventory_table.is_in_stock = 1)) OR  ((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 0) AND (1 - _inventory_table.manage_stock + _inventory_table.is_in_stock >= 1))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',
            array()
        );
        $collection->getSelect()->order('on_top DESC');
        $order = $collection->getSelect()->getPart('order');
        array_unshift($order, array_pop($order));
        $collection->getSelect()->setPart('order', $order);
```

Now what is happening is I can see the products from low to high but not out-of-stock products last.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Mage::getResourceModel('cataloginventory/stock_status')
    ->addStockStatusToSelect($select, Mage::app()->getWebsite());`
```

And then sort by `salable desc`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use another event, catalog_product_collection_load_before is useless because Mage_Review Module-Observer loads the product list collection so you cant edit this collection any more. You can disable this observer if you dont use reviews or do it like described here:

[catalog_product_collection_load_before and getLoadedProductCollection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40888/catalog-product-collection-load-before-and-getloadedproductcollection/40968#40968)

Regards

Comment: If the collection is loaded, the `catalog_product_collection_load_before` event is dispatched here: `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::_beforeLoad`, so it should work.