# Show product only within a date range (between start date and end date)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, product, date

I want to create a product with **start date** and **end date**.
Once the end date comes the product should be hidden from the product listing.
Are there any methods to complete this task?

I tried with **product new from date** and  **product new to date**, it is not giving me the desired result.

Comment: you just have to set the CRON on server when it would reach the end date of the products.. It would make it disabled

Comment: @Manashvibirla how to add an end date to a product while adding a product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest,

Create new  two date attribute  product attribute.W

- `available_from_date` ->the start date from where the product `will be show on product listing`
- available_to_date  ->the end date from where the product w`will be stop on product listing`

**This  two attribute manage the product wise available time .Just like h product new from date and product new to date.**

Now you need to set product those two field value from admin

Then using below events  filter the product collection by :

- `catalog_block_product_list_collection` (used by review module, after
  collection is loaded its not editable anymore)
- `catalog_product_collection_load_before`
- `catalog_product_collection_load_after`

See [catalog_product_collection_load_before and getLoadedProductCollection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40888/catalog-product-collection-load-before-and-getloadedproductcollection)

Then make event area `fronted` thus event  `will fire on frontend area`

Example using event:

```
<frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_collection_load_after> <!- event -->

                <observers>
                    <pset_product_avaliable>
                        <class>YourModuleNameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>collectiondatefilter</method>
                    </pset_product_avaliable>>              
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_collection_load_after>        
        </events>
```

On event filter the collection by  below code:

```
         $todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('00:00:00')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $todayEndOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('23:59:59')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('available_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('available_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'available_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'available_to_date, 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                    )
              );
```

**Observer look like:**

```
 public function collectiondatefilter($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

        $todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('00:00:00')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $todayEndOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('23:59:59')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);


    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('available_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('available_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'available_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'available_to_date, 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                    )
              );

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: I am following this solution but products are not being filtered

Answer (score 2):

You would need to develop this yourself, or maybe take a look to this extension: http://shop.ecomdev.org/scheduled-products.html

If you would like to give it a try you could create a cronjob that checks the end date of the products and disable them.

In your module config.xml:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <mymodule_disable>
            <schedule>
                <!-- every 10 min -->
                <cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>mymodule/Scheduler::disable</model>
            </run>
        </mymodule_disable>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

And the method to disable the products:

```
public static function disable()
{
     $date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate();
     $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
     $collection->addfieldtofilter('end_data', array(
         array('gteq' => $date)
     ));
     foreach($collection as $product) {
         $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
         $product->save();
     }
}
```

You would need to adjust this code to your specific needs, but this should do the trick. Credit goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15295686/1016425

If you need to add an attribute to your products, then add a new attribute called end_date and assign the attribute to the attribute set you are using for your products. Check here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqhCcCpR4DI

Another possibility would be to rewrite the block for category details and product details, and then when you get the product collection filter by end_date there. In this case you don't need a cron.

Comment: how to set the end date in admin panel while adding the product?

Comment: I updated my answer, check how to add the attribute. Then the new attribute will be available at the product edit page in the backend.

Comment: yes that's fine, i guess is there any thing already exist in the magento rather than creating an attribute.Thank you very much.

Comment: Then go for one of the existing modules, check the first link in my answer. Also if this helped you consider accepting the answer. Thanks and let me know if you need more details

Comment: The ecomdev link doesn't appear to go to an active extension on magento connect, but there is also a detailed description here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26365562/3779933

Answer (score 2):

Try This Code:-

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000);
    ini_set('post_max_size', '5000M');
    ini_set("memory_limit","4046M");
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5000M');
    require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);


    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                           ->getCollection()                        
                           ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                           ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
                           ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                           0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                           1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                       ), 'left')
                        ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
                           ->load();
    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)
    {
      echo $_product->getStatus().'</br>';

      echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
      echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
      echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';
      echo $_product->getimage().'</br>';
      echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';

    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a product attribute "Visible to Date" for this.

And than just write a CRON job that checks all the active products for "Visible to Date" values. If the value is before the current date, disable the product. And so the product won't be visible in Frontend.

Comment: This is not a good idea imho, since you could have other modules that use this attribute, or he could alredy be using this himself. In any case this could give you some headaches in the future. It's better to create the attribute you need.

Comment: True. In any case, the CRON job will do the work for you.

Comment: Yes, the cron is needed in both cases.