# View Date-based Products

Tags: product, module, orders, custom, date

I run a food delivery business where we make fresh food, package it, and delivery it locally each day. Each day we offer a different set of options. For example, on Monday there might be Entree A, Entree B, Salad A, and Salad B. On Tuesday, there would be Entree B, Entree C, Salad B, and Salad C.

We'd love to create an online store with Magento where our customers are able to view our menus 1-2 weeks in advance and place orders for those items. For example, on Monday, a customer could order food for Thursday and Friday. However, we won't make or deliver those items until those given days.

Is there an extension or a way to do this in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might want to look into a pre-order module.

I currently use this one from Amasty: https://amasty.com/magento-pre-order.html

Comment: You'll also want to investigate having a delivery date option on your checkout page. Most of the top OPC extensions offer this.

Comment: Follow-up question: Is there anyway for me to only have certain products available for certain days and not others?

Comment: I'm sure there's an extension out there for that, however checkout this previous thread: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72067/show-product-only-within-a-date-range-between-start-date-and-end-date